# problem with assembly code after rewriting with 16bit

Tags: assembly, masm32

I've had an assembly (MASM x86) code for doing this C++ equation

```cpp
void main()
{
unsigned int i, B[10], A[10]={3,2,3,1,7,5,0,8,9,2}; 
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
B[i] = A[i] + 2 * (2*i + ( (3*i+1) / 5) );
}
```

it's working when I use 32bit registers and variables but after changing them to use 16bit
it returns some errors.

**The assembly code**

```
.386  ; Specify instruction set
.model flat, stdcall  ; Flat memory model, std. calling convention
.stack 4096 ; Reserve stack space
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: WORD  ; Exit process prototype

.data
    A WORD  3,2,3,1,7,5,0,8,9,2  
    B WORD  10 DUP (?)                    
                            
    var1 WORD 0
    quotient WORD 0

 ; A[i] + 2 * (2*i + ( (3*i+1) / 5) )
.code      
main PROC
    mov si, 0                  

loop_start:

    ;(3*i+1)
    mov ax, 3                    
    mul si                      
    inc ax                   
    
    ; / 5)
    mov dx,0   
    mov cx,5
    div cx    
    mov quotient,ax

    ; 2*i
    mov ax,2                           
    mul si     

    ; (2*i + ( (3*i+1) / 5) )
    mov bx, quotient
    add ax,bx
   
   ; 2 * (2*i + ( (3*i+1) / 5) )
   mov var1,2
   mul var1
   mov var1, ax
  
    ; load array A
    lea bx,A
    mov cx,4

    ;A[i] + 2 * (2*i + ( (3*i+1) / 5) )
    ;imul dx,si 
    ;mov bx, dx
    mov ax,[bx + TYPE A * si]
    add bx,var1
   
   ;load array B and store
    lea ax,B
    mov  [ax + dx], bx

    ; i<10; i++
    inc si                   
    cmp si, 10                 
    jl loop_start  

INVOKE ExitProcess, 0 ; call exit function
  
main ENDP ; exit main procedure
END main  ; stop assembling
```

The error I'm getting is  `error A2031: Must be index or base register` on `mov ax,[bx + TYPE A * si]` when I'm trying to read array index

As far as I know the bx is a base registry, I also add `bx` with `si` outside of the `[]` but still doesn't work!

**Update**

Is there anyway to run fix this code without using 32bit indexes, registers and variables?

Comment: Read up on 16 bit addressing modes.  They are quite restricted in comparison to the 32 and 64 bit addressing modes.

Comment: On way to work around the limitation is to have one register for `i`, and a separate register as a byte offset (`2*i`) that you increment by 2 every iteration.  Also, your C function the arrays as non-`static` local variables, so if you want to be faithful to that, you'd have reserve stack space and use 2 different offsets from `bp` for your arrays, like `[bp + si - 20]` or `[bp + si - 40]`.

Comment: Just for fun, I was curious what compilers would do with that expression.  https://godbolt.org/z/Ta6Y75Pva shows Clang `-O2` puts `A[]` in static storage even though it's non-const, as long as you don't make it `volatile`.  (I made `B[]` `volatile` so it wouldn't get optimized away.)  Looks like clang uses ECX to hold `1+ 3*i` instead of redoing that part every iteration (it would just take one LEA, but even cheaper not to do it at all.)  And ESI holds `4*i`, used as a byte offset into the arrays and as `2 * (2*i + ...` with `lea  eax, [esi + 2*edx]` (where EDX holds the `.../5` quotient).

Comment: (As for why EDX holds the quotient after `mul`/`shr edx,2`, that's [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935))

Comment: *Is there anyway to run fix this code without using 32bit indexes, registers and variables?* Yes, of course; I suggested one in an earlier comment: use `si`, `di`, or `bx` to hold a byte-offset.  There are lots of other ways to go about it, e.g. to copy `i` to another register and left-shift by 1 to double it, since you're using `sizeof(int) == 2` (1 word) in your 16-bit version.  Then since you're using static arrays, `mov ax, [A + si]` or whatever.  Or if you have pointers in SI and DI, you can compute an offset in BX.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, I'll try to apply your suggestions on it. I'm a Mac user, don't have a windows machine around to test it, but I'll try this afternoon.

Comment: JWASM is MASM-compatible for syntax but is portable and might work on a Mac, although I guess it you could probably only target 64-bit mode unless you have a MacOS version that's a few years old.  Still, you can use 16-bit operand-size for everything except pointer increments, and  limit your code to only things that have direct equivalents for 16-bit address-size (like addressing modes such as `[rbx + rsi]`)

Comment: Or just test stuff inside DOSBox with a DOS assembler?  But wait, you're using 16-bit address-size but calling Windows `ExitProcess`?  I'm not sure that works; Windows programs run in at least 32-bit mode so label addresses are 32-bit pointers that won't fit in 16-bit.  Unless you're targeting 16-bit code on Windows 3.11 or something (16-bit protected mode.)